# matrices/ invertible matrices

Tags: matrices

I am new to linear algebra and I was wondering if I could get some help on 3 problems. Thanks for all the tips.

Q1: $A = PBP^{-1}$ Solve for B, where P is an invertible matrix.

What I did:

$A = P^{-1}PBP^{-1}P$
$P^{-1}AP = B$

Q2: $C^{-1}(A+X)B^{-1} = I$ , where A,B, and C are invertible matrices solve for X

What I did:

$[C^{-1}A+C^{-1}X]B^{-1} = I$

$C^{-1}AB^{-1}+C^{-1}XB^{-1} = I$

$CC^(-1)AA^{-1}B^{-1}B + CC^{-1}XB^{-1}B = I$

$X = A(CIA^{-1}B)B$

Q3: ($I-A)(I + A + A^2 + .... + A^n)$

What I did:

$I^2 + \sum_{i=2}^{n} [IA^i] + \sum_{i}^{n} [-A^k]$

Are my answers correct? I feel that it is too simple..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to question 1 looks ok.

For question 2, do something like what you did in question 1 to remove the factors $C^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$.  Then subtract $A$ to get $X$ by itself.

For question 3, if you look at how things multiply out, you will see that a lot of the terms add to $\bf{0}$, and so some simplification is possible.

Comment: Thank You for all the help!